# Automatic user creation and authentication using Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing web app using laravel. when a client/office create an account in my app they have the provision for adding their staffs. when they add a staff app should create a account for them under the client/office account and should assign a temporary username and password for them to log in to the app.

My Problems:

- How can i implement automatic registration of users
- how to assign temporary username and password for them
  I am using laravel 5.6 with homestead and php

Any help and suggestion are appreciated

thanks
rufaidulk

Comment: did you mean php artisan make:auth ?

Comment: When you setup the relationships in Laravel, you can do something like `$client->staff->create(['username' => 'temp', 'password' => 'temp']);` Look at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships (p.s. I think you need a `many to many` relationship, because clients can have many staff and staff can belong to many clients. If that last part is not true, it should be a `one to many` relationship.

Comment: Also please show us the code you already wrote.

Comment: i am just used default authentication in laravel

Answer (score 1):

You can create users like you do for other models:

```
User::create([
  ...
  "email"=>$request->email, 
  "password"=>Hash::make($request->password)
  ...
]);
```

Try adding some validation first, and check that the user creating the account has all required permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You could run `php artisan make:auth` in the console, this will create the routes, controllers and migrations for the user auth process

then in the register controller that was generated you could create the user and authenticate them with

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'email'      => $data['email'],
            'password'   => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ...
        ]);
    }
```